# Paging when using multi-level (nested) entities with (SQL) Views in Entity Framework (MVC 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I am working on an MVC 5.0 Entity Framework application. I have an Entry class, and every Entry can have sub-entries. Here is a brief snapshot of the Entry class:

```
public class Entry
{
    public int? EntryId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int? ParentEntryId { get; set; }
    public int EntryDepthness { get; set; }
}
```

ParentEntryId is null only for the main entries, and EntryDepthness is 0 for the main entry and increases by 1 for each sub-entry.

I am using an SQL View to read the entries (I am doing this because there is User information that I did not include in the class definition above):

```
var entryviews = db.Database
                   .SqlQuery<ViewEntryRecord>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ViewEntryRecords] ORDER BY Date DESC ")
                   .ToList();
foreach (var entryview in entryviews)
{
    ////other code
}
```

Everything works fine. However, I am not sure how to implement paging here since the query above will return a mix of entries with different EntryDepthness values. I want to display, let's say, first 3 (main) Entries (with depth = 0) but also bring the sub-entries (only depth = 1) for the main entries.

```
Entry1
---SubEntry11 (has 4 sub-entries)
---SubEntry12 (has 2 sub-entries)
Entry2
---SubEntry2 
Entry3
---SubEntry3 (has 1 sub-entries)
```

To implement paging, do I have to drop using Sql View? Can anyone help about the logic?

Comment: This is more about UI patterns than anything else. You should probably ask this question at [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: your question is not very clear to me,but if you want to do pagination using EF you might need to use Skip and Take function.
 db.Database
                   .SqlQuery<ViewEntryRecord>("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ViewEntryRecords] ORDER BY Date DESC ")
                   .Skip(#pagenumber)
                    .Take(#of items to show)
                   .ToList();